# N/datasetLink with Dataset Builder Plug-In: How to display the data after linking the sets?

Tags: netsuite, data-linking

Code example below... After creating my linkedDataset how do I display it? I understand it has to do something with the context.dataset but I cant get it to work. I missing something... Any ideas?

var salesRebatesData = datasetLib.load({
id: 'custdataset30'
});

var rebatePlansData = datasetLib.load({
id: 'custdataset29'
});

var srGroupCode = salesRebatesData.getExpressionFromColumn({
alias: 'entitycustomercustentity_pls_uk_customer_group_codename'
});

var rpGroupName = rebatePlansData.getExpressionFromColumn({
alias: 'custrecord_pls_cust_grpname'
});

var myDatasetLink = datasetLinkLib.create({

```
    datasets: [salesRebatesData, rebatePlansData],
    expressions: [[srGroupCode, rpGroupName]],
    id: 'sales_rebates_dataset'

});
```